# Conditionally show column data as an alias in a SQL view based on other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a View that will combine several columns into a single column, based on different conditions. This data is the result of a flat file parsing.

Here is an example of the raw data in the table:

```
LabelText   ValueText   ValueDecimal   ValueDate   ValueType
------------------------------------------------------------
Task #      1234-45     0.00           1/1/1900    Text
Start Date              0.00           3/4/2019    Date
Cost                    120.32         1/1/1900    Decimal
Note        Note text   0.00           1/1/1900    Comment
```

I would like to take this data and end up with a view that looks like this:

```
LabelText    ValueDisplay   
-------------------------
Task #       1234-45
StartDate    3/4/2019
Cost         120.32
Note         Note text
```

I am not sure a pivot table will work and so I was thinking about CASE WHEN in SQL. I am not sure if I can refer to a column name in a case when like this

```
CASE WHEN [VALUETYPE] = 'Text' THEN [ValueText] AS ValueDisplay

CASE WHEN [VALUETYPE] = 'Date' THEN [ValueDate] AS ValueDisplay

CASE WHEN [VALUETYPE] = 'Decimal' THEN [ValueDecimal] AS ValueDisplay
```

That would be what I am trying to get, but I am not sure how to get there.

Comment: You code appears correct - what are you having trouble with? I guess you might need a tweak to get a multi-option case working, but thats trivial from the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UNION ALL` will work better in this situation:

```
SELECT
t.LabelText,
t.ValueText as ValueDisplay
from table1 t
where t.ValueType = 'Text'

UNION ALL

SELECT
t.LabelText,
t.ValueDate as ValueDisplay
from table1 t
where t.ValueType = 'Date'

UNION ALL

SELECT
t.LabelText,
t.ValueDecimal as ValueDisplay
from table1 t
where t.ValueType = 'Decimal'

UNION ALL

SELECT
t.LabelText,
t.ValueText as ValueDisplay
from table1 t
where t.ValueType = 'Comment';
```

Result:

```
|  LabelText | ValueDisplay |
|------------|--------------|
|     Task # |      1234-45 |
| Start Date |     3/4/2019 |
|       Cost |       120.32 |
|       Note |    Note text |
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b9335/4)

Comment: Would the performance better on this method than CASE or CONCAT?

Comment: That would depend on many factors. But if the volume was significantly high and indexes were in place, I would say yes. `WHERE` clauses like the above are *generally* more efficient at filtering data than using `CASE` or `CONCAT` statements. At small volumes there might not be much of a difference. But check your Explain Plan to make sure.

Comment: Also consider scalability and readability. You could combine conditions like the `Text` and `Comment` types using an `IN` clause. Adding more conditions should also be simpler and less messier than many `CASE` statements.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps concat() would help here

**Example**

```
Select [LabelText] 
      ,ValueDisplay = concat(''
                            , case when [VALUETYPE] = 'Date'    then [ValueDate]    end
                            , case when [VALUETYPE] = 'Decimal' then [ValueDecimal] end
                            , case when [VALUETYPE] = 'Text'    then [ValueText]    end
                            , case when [VALUETYPE] = 'Comment' then [ValueText]    end
                           ) 
 From YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
LabelText   ValueDisplay
Task #      1234-45
Start Date  2019-03-04
Cost        120.32
Note        Note text
```

Comment: @Ryan Happy to help